# Raspberry Pi 3 and Arduino

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, raspberry-pi3, arduino-ide

For my project I am trying to connect a Raspberry Pi 3 with an Arduino Nano. I can't find any information about specifically connecting Raspberry Pi 3 and Arduino serially. I have found a lot of guides for the Raspberry Pi 2 and Arduino, however when I follow the instructions, I find that there are some updated files that fail somewhere along the line.

So in short, is it possible to connect the Raspberry Pi 3 and the Arduino Nano serially? If so, are there any links to this?

Thank you.

Comment: just learn how to do serial communication with raspi3  and arduino separately, then you'lll know how to link both. you should not search the web for special problems only. break it down and search for the bricks

Answer (score 0):

You must conect it same that this image:

[image]